# (Solution verification and criticism) If wff $\phi$ has no repetition of sentence letters, then $\nvDash \phi$

Tags: logic, proof-writing, solution-verification, metalogic

**Edit:** Here is attempt number 2. I've been much more terse, which I think flows much better. I've also changed the binary connective to disjunction to improve readability as well. By truth table $\lnot\phi \to \psi$ is equivalent to $\phi \lor \psi$, so it's justified.

*L1:* Iff $\nvDash \phi$, then there exists a PL-interpretation, $\mathscr{I}$, such that $V_\mathscr{I}(\phi)=0$. Iff $V_\mathscr{I}(\phi)=0$, then $V_\mathscr{I}(\lnot\phi)=1$. In other words, iff $\lnot \phi$ can be satisfied, which it can be iff there exists an $\mathscr{I}$ such that $V_\mathscr{I}(\phi)=0$, then it isn't a tautology.

*Base case:* Let wff $\phi$ be composed of a single sentence letter with an $\mathscr{I}$ such that $V_\mathscr{I}(\phi)=0$, thus, from L1, $\nvDash \phi$.

*Induction hypothesis (IH):* Let $\phi$ be composed of a finite number of sentence letters that don't appear more than once. Assume it holds that an $\mathscr{I}$ exists such that $V_\mathscr{I}(\phi)=0$.

*Induction step:*

- From the IH, $V_\mathscr{I}(\phi)=0$, so $V_\mathscr{I}(\lnot \phi)=1$, thus $\nvDash \phi$
- Let $\psi$ be composed of a single sentence letter that doesn't appear in $\phi$ with an $\mathscr{I}$ such that V$_\mathscr{I}(\psi)=0$. It follows that $V_\mathscr{I}(\phi \lor \psi)=0$, thus $\nvDash (\phi \lor \psi)$

---

I'm really trying to up my game when it comes to proofs. I'd greatly appreciate it if someone could check that my proof is correct, and, if so, offer ways to improve readability, style, structure, etc. Thanks in advance

---

> Exercise 2.8$^1$: Show that if wff $\phi$ has no repetition of sentence letters (i.e., each sentence letter occurs at most once in $\phi$) then $\nvDash \phi.$

---

**Definitions:**

A. Language:

- Classic propositional logic (PL)

B. Primitive Vocabulary$^2$:

- Connectives: $\to$, $\lnot$
- Sentence letters: $P, Q, R\ldots,$ with or without numerical subscripts
- Parentheses: (, )

C. Definition of wff$\,^3$:

1. Every sentence letter is a PL-wff
2. If $\phi$ and $\psi$ are PL-wffs, then $(\phi \to \psi)$ and $\lnot \phi$ are also PL-wffs
3. Only strings that can be shown to be PL-wffs using (1) and (2) are PL-wffs

D. Definition of interpretation$^4$:

- A PL-interpretation is a function $\mathscr{I}$, that assigns to each sentence letter either $1$ or $0$.

E. Definition of valuation$^5$: For any PL-interpretation, $\mathscr{I}$, the PL-valuation for $\mathscr{I}$, $V_\mathscr{I}$, is defined as the function that assigns to each wff either $1$ or $0$, and which is such that, for any sentence letter $\alpha$ and any wffs $\phi$ and $\psi$:

1. $V_\mathscr{I}(\alpha)=\mathscr{I}(\alpha)$
2. $V_\mathscr{I}(\lnot \phi)=1$ iff $V_\mathscr{I}(\phi)=0$
3. $V_\mathscr{I}(\phi \to \psi)=1$ iff either $V_\mathscr{I}(\phi)=0$ or $V_\mathscr{I}(\psi)=1$

F. Definition of validity$^6$:

- A wff $\phi$ is PL-valid, $\vDash \phi$, iff for every PL-interpretation, $\mathscr{I}$, $V_\mathscr{I}(\phi)=1$

---

**Proof**

We will prove (2.8) via induction.

*Base case:*

Let wff $\phi$ be composed of a single sentence letter, $\alpha$. From (D) we can choose a PL-interpretation, $\mathscr{I}$, such that, $\mathscr{I}(\alpha)=1$ and we can choose an $\mathscr{I}$ such that $\mathscr{I}(\alpha)=0$. From (E1), $V_\mathscr{I}(\phi)=\mathscr{I}(\alpha)$, so there exists an $\mathscr{I}$ where $V_\mathscr{I}(\phi)=1$ and there exists an $\mathscr{I}$ where $V_\mathscr{I}(\phi)=0$. Thus, there exists a PL-interpretation such that $V_\mathscr{I}(\phi)\neq 1$, so, from (F), $\nvDash \phi$.

*Induction hypothesis (IH):*

Let $\phi$ and $\psi$ be wffs that don't share any sentence letters, $\alpha$, or contain any $\alpha$ that occur more than once. Assume it holds that a PL-interpretation, $\mathscr{I}$, exists such that $V_\mathscr{I}(\phi)=1$ and
there exists an $\mathscr{I}$ where $V_\mathscr{I}(\phi)=0$, and there exists an $\mathscr{I}$ where $V_\mathscr{I}(\psi)=1$ and there exists an $\mathscr{I}$ where $V_\mathscr{I}(\psi)=0$, and thus there exists a PL-interpretation such that $V_\mathscr{I}(\phi)\neq 1$ and $V_\mathscr{I}(\psi)\neq 1$, so $\nvDash \phi$ and $\nvDash \psi$.

*Induction step:*

- From the (IH), choose a PL-interpretation such that $V_\mathscr{I}(\phi)=1$. From (E2), $V_\mathscr{I}(\lnot \phi)=0$, thus $\nvDash \lnot \phi$
- From the (IH), choose a PL-interpretation such that V$_\mathscr{I}(\phi)=1$ and $V_\mathscr{I}(\psi)=0$. From (E3), $V_\mathscr{I}(\phi \to \psi)=0$, thus $\nvDash \phi \to \psi$ ■

---

$\tiny\text{1. Sider, T., 2010. Logic for philosophy. Oxford: Oxford University Press, p.55}$$\tiny\text{2. Sider, T., 2010. Logic for philosophy. Oxford: Oxford University Press, p.25}$$\tiny\text{3. Sider, T., 2010. Logic for philosophy. Oxford: Oxford University Press, p.26}$$\tiny\text{4. Sider, T., 2010. Logic for philosophy. Oxford: Oxford University Press, p.29}$$\tiny\text{5. Sider, T., 2010. Logic for philosophy. Oxford: Oxford University Press, p.30}$$\tiny\text{6. Sider, T., 2010. Logic for philosophy. Oxford: Oxford University Press, p.34}$

Comment: Negation case: by IH you have that there is an int I such that $V_I(\phi) \ne 1$. But what happens if it is always $0$ ?

Comment: As correctly suggested by @MauroALLEGRANZA's comment, I guess you have to prove a stronger statement to have the right inductive hypothesis. Do you see which statement you need?

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA, I'm not following. Do you see a way to lock in a specific property rather than the ability to choose?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco, I'm not following. Mauro, is making a choice that isn't forced by the definitions so it doesn't need to be made?

Comment: I can make it more explicit that we can choose an interpretation in the base case and IH?

Comment: What you can prove is that, under the hypothesis above, $\phi$ is neither a tautology nor a contradiction. The base case is correct also in this stronger case.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA, I've changed from "or" to "and", which I think locks down. For it all to hold, I think, there just needs to be a guarantee that an IPLI can be selected. I am assuming that I don't need to spell out that $\alpha$ can be independently assigned?

Comment: Regarding the Induction step in the case of a binary connective, there is no reason that the interpretation I is the same for both formulas; here the condition of no common sentence letter is crucial.

Comment: Sure, but other than mentioning it in the IH, does it need explicitly stating that the truth assignment of 1 sentence letter doesn't affect the other? It's explicitly stated what the valuations of phi and psi are, so can mix and match 

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA, I see what you're getting at now. If $\lnot \phi$ can be satisfied then it can't be a tautology, thus $\nvDash \phi$, and, iff that's true for all wffs under consideration, which induction would prove, then it can't be a contradiction either. So if we set $V_I(\phi)=0$, we prove the base case, and for the IS we might be better off using disjunction than a conditional  I'll have another go tomorrow, my cryptic friend  and thanks for your time

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA, I've added attempt number 2 to my post 

Answer (score 2):

As @Taroccoesbrocco noted in the comments, we need to prove a stronger conclusion: *if the wff $\phi$ has no repetition of sentence letters then $\phi$ is neither a tautology nor a contradiction*.

*Proof.* By induction on $\phi$.

1. $\phi=\alpha$ for some sentence letter $\alpha$. Pick interpretations $\mathscr{I}_1$ and $\mathscr{I}_0$ such that $\mathscr{I}_1(\alpha)=1$ and $\mathscr{I}_0(\alpha)=0$, and so $V_{\mathscr{I}_1}(\phi)=V_{\mathscr{I}_1}(\alpha)=\mathscr{I}_1(\alpha)=1$ and $V_{\mathscr{I}_0}(\phi)=V_{\mathscr{I}_0}(\alpha)=\mathscr{I}_0(\alpha)=0$ which follow that $\phi$ is neither a tautology nor a contradiction.
2. $\phi=\neg\psi$ for some $\mathrm{PL}$-$\mathrm{wff}$. By induction hypothesis that $\psi$ is neither a tautology nor a contradiction, there are some interpretations $\mathscr{I}_1$ and $\mathscr{I}_0$ such that $V_{\mathscr{I}_1}(\psi)=1$ and $V_{\mathscr{I}_0}(\psi)=0$, and so by Definition of valuation$^5$ we have $V_{\mathscr{I}_1}(\phi)=0$ and $V_{\mathscr{I}_0}(\psi)=1$ which follows that $\phi$ is neither a tautology nor a contradiction.
3. $\phi=\psi\to\theta$ for some $\mathrm{PL}$-$\mathrm{wff}$s $\psi,\theta$. By induction hypothesis that $\psi$ and $\theta$ are neither a tautologies nor contradictions, there is some interpretation $\mathscr{I}_1$ such that $V_{\mathscr{I}_1}(\psi)=1$, and there are some interpretations $\mathscr{J}_1$ and $\mathscr{J}_0$ such that $V_{\mathscr{J}_1}(\theta)=1$ and $V_{\mathscr{J}_0}(\theta)=0$.

(1) In one way, by Definition of valuation$^5$ we have $V_{\mathscr{J}_1}(\phi)=V_{\mathscr{J}_1}(\psi\to\theta)=1$ which follows that $\phi$ is not a contradiction.

(2) In another way we define ${\mathscr{I}_0}^*$ whose domain is the set of all sentence letters as follows:

$$
{\mathscr{I}_0}^*(\alpha)=
\begin{cases}
{\mathscr{I}_1}(\alpha)&\alpha\text{ occurs in }\psi,\\
{\mathscr{J}_0}(\alpha)&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
Since $\phi$ has no repetition of sentence letters, then ${\mathscr{I}_0}^*$ and ${\mathscr{I}_1}$ agree on sentence letters in $\psi$, and ${\mathscr{I}_0}^*$ and ${\mathscr{J}_0}$ agree on sentence letters in $\theta$. Then( by Exercise 2.7 on page 70 of your textbook) we have $V_{{\mathscr{I}_0}^*}(\psi)=1$ iff $V_{{\mathscr{I}_1}}(\psi)=1$ and $V_{{\mathscr{I}_0}^*}(\theta)=0$ iff $V_{{\mathscr{J}_0}}(\theta)=0$, and so $V_{{\mathscr{I}_0}^*}(\psi)=1$ and $V_{{\mathscr{I}_0}^*}(\theta)=0$. Therefore by Definition of valuation$^5$ we have $V_{{\mathscr{I}_0}^*}(\phi)=V_{{\mathscr{I}_0}^*}(\psi\to\theta)=0$ which follows that $\phi$ is not a tautology.

**Remark.** The assumption that $\phi$ has no repetition of sentence letters is used in the implication formula case.

Comment: Thanks for that, indexing the interpretations to allow selection was basically the route I was trying to go down (sans indexing lol). I found a different approach that I've added in to my post, see what you think 

Comment: @Ten O'Four That's not right either.

Comment: How so? If $\lnot \phi$ is satisfiable it isn't a tautology. It can't be a contradiction either

Comment: But what you need to show is that $\neg\phi$ isn't a tautology, i.e., $\neg\phi$ could be false for some interpretation, i.e., $\phi$ is true for some interpretation.

Comment: I explained the prev comment badly, 2nd try . As we're doing induction on formula construction, any formula can be reached. So let's say there is a tautology of the form $\lnot \psi$, we can reach it by the IH, so $\phi = \lnot\psi$, but $V_I(\phi)=0$, which would contradict it being a tautology. I'll think about how to make it clearer. Should I add something like "we can set $\psi$ to what we like as it doesn't appear in $\phi$ it can't change the valuation"? Or can I assume peeps know that? I've not really found the balance between readable and teaching peeps to suck eggs yet :/

Comment: Maybe proving in CNF/DNF forms during induction on the complexity of a general formula is better for utility of the intuition of no repetition of propositional symbols to be non-tautological?